# How to set a dconf keybinding to use <AltGraph> key?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, dconf

In Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver with GNOME 3 we can use dconf to set a lot o keybindings. What is the syntax to associate <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (that is right Alt) to a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AltGr key is used as a modifier to other keys on many layouts, so I guess that's why it can't be used. On my layout, Norwegian, AltGr+2 makes @, for instance.